# MVC 4 application giving a 404 when deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project using .NET 4.5 that I am trying to publish to IIS 7.0 using Visual Studio 2012. When I debug the application in IIS Express everything works wonderfully. When I publish it to the server, the MVC requests return 404. I have a few aspx pages on the site and they all work fine. Below is my routing scheme. It is boilerplate code:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Thanks.

**Edits:**

I got it! I had to add the following to `system.webServer` in my `web.config`:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Is MVC4 and .net 4.5 installed on the server?

Comment: Yes both are installed.

Comment: Well, I have .NET 4.5 installed, but what would I need to install on the server for MVC 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reference may help:

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules

"runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests previously had to be set to true to support routing. However, once IIS 7 has been updated with a Service Pack, the value of runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests can be set to false or omitted when working with ASP.NET routing."

(obviously installing an IIS or Windows service pack needs careful consideration first)

Comment: This was nearly 3 years ago. I don't even remember what project I was working on. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Reference : [Here](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/app_offline-htm-gotchas-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: That doesn't quite explain it for my specific problem.

Comment: This answer would be better if the content at the link was summarized here in case the link dies