# Why is my ASP.NET MVC View page returning 404?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing a website for a friend where she can show off her goats.She would like the main site to function as a blog, and then include a database for viewers to look at the goats she owns. I started with the ASP.NET "Blank" web application template in Visual Studio 2013, with support checked for web forms and MVC. I downloaded and configured [BlogEngine.NET](http://dotnetblogengine.net/), and copied it into the project, choosing "include in project" from solution explorer. The blog part works perfectly.

Now, I would like to add the database part. I configured connection strings in `web.config`, then added a `Does` class to the `Model` folder. It looks something like this:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Doe
    'The registration number contains letters
    <Key>
    <Display(Name:="Registration #")>
    Public Property RegistryNumber As String

    <Required>
    <Display(Name:="Name")>
    Public Property FullName As String

    <Required>
    <DataType(DataType.Date)>
    <Display(Name:="Birthday")>
    <DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:="{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}")>
    Public Property BirthDate As Date

    Public ReadOnly Property PedigreeLink() As String
        Get
            Return "http://adgagenetics.org/GoatDetail.aspx?RegNumber=" & RegistryNumber.ToString()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class DoeDbContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Does As DbSet(Of Doe)

End Class
```

After writing the `Doe` model, I right-clicked the `Controllers` folder, clicked `Add new controller`, and created an `MVC 5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework`. I have not in any way modified the controller or the views from the way they were initially set up.

**Edit** This is the full code in my `App_Start\RouteConfig.vb`

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Routing

Public Module RouteConfig
    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

        routes.MapRoute(
             name:="Default",
             url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        )

         routes.MapRoute(name:="Shorthand", url:="{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}")

    End Sub
End Module
```

However, when I attempt to debug the application and type `https://localhost:xxxx/does/index` into the address bar, I receive the following 404 error:

[image: HTTP 404 Error Page screenshot]

I have added the following code to my `web.config` per the advice [here](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/testing-and-debugging/aspnet-web-pages-razor-troubleshooting-guide):

```
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <remove fileExtension=".cshtml" />
          <add fileExtension=".cshtml" allowed="true" />
          <remove fileExtension=".vbhtml" />
          <add fileExtension=".vbhtml" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

Copying code out of an MVC that worked, I also added

```
     <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
```

I have also tried using Phil Haack's [routedebugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/2.1.5) to troubleshoot, but receive a `Server Error in '/' Application. Sequence contains no elements` error when trying to access *any* pages within the application after installing the package.

How can I fix this so I can keep the blog portion, and allow the MVC parts to work?

**Edit 2** Here is my controller

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports MyProjectName_Database

Namespace Controllers
    Public Class DoesController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Private db As New DoeDbContext

        ' GET: Does
        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View(db.Does.ToList())
        End Function

        ' GET: Does/Details/5
        Function Details(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
            If IsNothing(id) Then
                Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            End If
            Dim doe As Doe = db.Does.Find(id)
            If IsNothing(doe) Then
                Return HttpNotFound()
            End If
            Return View(doe)
        End Function

        ' GET: Does/Create
        Function Create() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function

        ' POST: Does/Create
        'To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        'more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        <HttpPost()>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
        Function Create(<Bind(Include:="RegistryNumber,FullName,BirthDate")> ByVal doe As Doe) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                db.Does.Add(doe)
                db.SaveChanges()
                Return RedirectToAction("Index")
            End If
            Return View(doe)
        End Function

        ' GET: Does/Edit/5
        Function Edit(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
            If IsNothing(id) Then
                Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            End If
            Dim doe As Doe = db.Does.Find(id)
            If IsNothing(doe) Then
                Return HttpNotFound()
            End If
            Return View(doe)
        End Function

        ' POST: Does/Edit/5
        'To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        'more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        <HttpPost()>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
        Function Edit(<Bind(Include:="RegistryNumber,FullName,BirthDate")> ByVal doe As Doe) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                db.Entry(doe).State = EntityState.Modified
                db.SaveChanges()
                Return RedirectToAction("Index")
            End If
            Return View(doe)
        End Function

        ' GET: Does/Delete/5
        Function Delete(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
            If IsNothing(id) Then
                Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            End If
            Dim doe As Doe = db.Does.Find(id)
            If IsNothing(doe) Then
                Return HttpNotFound()
            End If
            Return View(doe)
        End Function

        ' POST: Does/Delete/5
        <HttpPost()>
        <ActionName("Delete")>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
        Function DeleteConfirmed(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
            Dim doe As Doe = db.Does.Find(id)
            db.Does.Remove(doe)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
            If (disposing) Then
                db.Dispose()
            End If
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Do you have "Does" controller, is that correctly configured in routing ?

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha, Yes, I have the `DoesController`, as it was generated by the Visual Studio scaffolding. I have included my additions to the routing above.

Comment: @MilironX  blogengine somehow override your routing, check the reason, it should work.

Comment: Can you show the complete entry for your route?

Comment: @garethb, Sure thing, Have a look at my edit.

Comment: For clarity, you say you added a Does class but the code snippet shows a call title 'Doe'. Is this a typo? Also, are you sure your controller is Does and not Doe?

Comment: Sorry, Can you also show your controller class?

Comment: @garethb I have added the controller.

Comment: @puddinman13 Sorry, that is a typo. The class is `Doe`. I have added my controller code, if that clarifies whether it is `Does` or `Doe`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your setup, so might be something else. What version of .net are you running? What version of windows? Also, see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178821/mvc-4-application-giving-a-404-when-deployed

Comment: @garethb According to `clrver`, I'm running .net v.4.0.30319 on a Windows 8.1 machine (which should have .net 4.5.1 installed, odd). I checked my web.config, and `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is already equal to true.